# Powerbuilder 12.5 Word OLE bookmarks not populating

Tags: ms-word, ole, powerbuilder

I am trying to populate bookmarks on word template file(.dot)  using Powerbuilder 12.5

Not all the bookmarks are populated.I see like some bookmarks are not getting populated.
[image]

Code

```
ObjWord=create OLEOBject
Objword.connectToNewObject("Word.application")
objword.Documents.add("path to file.dot")
count=objWord.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Count
for ll_bookmark =1 to count
ls_bookmark=objword.ActiveDocument.bookmarks[ll_bookmark].name
objword.selection.goto(TRUE,0,0,ls_bookmark)
objword.selection.typetext('May 2014')
next
```

Comment: Code has been updated. @Seki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating @Mike's Answer.

My template had form fields and that is the reason the bookmarks were not updating.After changing all the fields to simple bookmarks the issue is resolved.

Thanks Mike.

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible it is a limitation of the GOTO function, I have not tried that before.

I did not try this with your code specifically, but the following has worked for me on PB12.1:

ActiveDocument.BookMarks.Item(ls_bookmark).SELECT

Comment: Bookmark select statement successfully selects all the bookmarks but when I use the typetext statement it only populates some bookmarks.The problem is the bookmarks were not accessible when I use typetext

Comment: If you don't need the bookmarks to be Fields, see if you using plain bookmarks instead changes anything.  If users won't be filling them in themselves ever, I'm not sure if there's an advantage to using fields.  In case it matters, bear in mind that the bookmark won't be automatically removed after typetext, like it is when it's a field (at least that's how I've seen them behave).  But there's a function for that if you needed it.

Comment: Can you please tell how to know the diff between fields and bookmarks? How to check if i have fields?Users wont be filling the data.

Comment: Also, I am converting this app from PB 6.5.Earlier the function had setformresult function and it is not working with latest version.Thanks for you support.

Comment: The gray boxes in your screenshot of the Word template look to me like they are fields, which are added through the Insert menu.  Bookmarks are assigned to them by right click->properties.  When a bookmark is assigned, you will see those brackets surrounding it.  They are capable of containing expressions and such, though in your scenario I'm guessing they are basically just bookmark "holders".  They are useful when a person is going to fill in the blanks, it gives them a box they can select with a single click and start typing.

Comment: But there is nothing wrong with fields unless you are recursively inserting/filling in the same template into another template multiple times.  You then have to make sure that the bookmarks are deleted if no text was actually written, otherwise the bookmark in the next iteration won't appear.  But that's probably neither here nor there.

Comment: I don't know about SetFormResult.  I found a couple examples in my application, but they date back to when we were using DDE instead of OLE.  It appears to have been used to check/uncheck a checkbox.  In case that is also how yours is using it, we use Selection.FormFields.Item(1).CheckBox.Value = true (after selecting the bookmark).

Comment: Thanks @Mike I removed all the greyed out fields and used a simple bookmark and it worked fine!! Thank you very much for your assistance.